# File-sync server software

Tags: share, synchronization, application

We are currently using Dropbox in the company and running out of space lately. I'm wondering if there any similar software that we could use on our own server?

I've looked at pogoplug, but I'd like to have some software that I could just install on a server and give apps to the users, and interface same as on dropbox with sharing and sync is needed.

Comment: Which operating systems (server & client)?

Comment: Windows, both server and client, but just post anything you got :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok: ready for some downvoting, here :P

If you plan to work with redmond you could use [offline files](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/windows/2006/11/21/using-offline-files.html) and windows share to work it out...

I know it's not perfectly what you need but on the other hand it's just my first answer :)

Comment: +1 - Offline Files on Windows clients works fairly well. It had some problems in Windows XP and got a lot better in Windows Vista / 7. It's not a requirement that you use a Microsoft SMB server to use it, either. In an Active Directory environment being able to administratively-assign offline files to clients is very handy, too.

Comment: thanks for answer. yeah it's not 100% what I'm looking for, but still good. The problem with offline files, is that they only work in network, I need a server & client apps so users could access files/sync files from home/work :s

Comment: @Maniak7: Offline files works fine over a VPN, too.

Comment: @Evan-Anderson: hmm, probably, but the interface still wouldn't be as nice as dropbox's. I mean managing permissions and stuff, it would be windows logins based rather than emails. Am I right? Also, web site where you can acess you files would also nice, but I'll try to stup VPN and see how it goes,thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [iFolder](http://www.ifolder.com/ifolder)? It's an opensource implementation of Dropbox. Of course, it still lacks of some important features of dropbox, but the project team is going in the right direction. Downside for you: Server is for OpenSuse.

Comment: I just had a look but I don't see the requirement the server has to be OpenSuse, can you post a link to that? The readme for the latest version only states "Your server must satisfy the following system requirements. 
 Openldap & 
 Apache 2 Web Server (worker mode) with SSL configured"

Comment: Its on their "Getting started" page here: [link] http://www.ifolder.com/ifolder/get_started
Clients are available for Windows, Linux and OSX, Server ist available via RPM for OpenSuSe (as they mention) or as source .tar.gz. (see [link] http://www.ifolder.com/download/

Comment: thanks a lot, I didn't hear about iFolder before. It's sad they don't have win server yet, but I'll bookmark the web site and see what I can do, thanks a lot:) that's exactly what I am looking for:)